# Question on finite subfamilies of an infinite family of sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be an infinite set, $B\subseteq A$ and $a\in B$. Let $X\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ be an infinite family of subsets of $A$ such that $a\in \bigcap X$.

Suppose $\bigcap X\subseteq B$. Is it possible that, for every non-empty finite subfamily $Y\subset X$, $\bigcap Y \not\subseteq B$ ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You mean for any non-empty finite $Y\subset X.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For a simple concrete example, let $A=\Bbb N$, $B=\{2n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, $a=0$, and

$$\mathscr{X}=\{\Bbb N\setminus\{2n+1\}:n\in\Bbb N\}\;.$$

$\bigcap\mathscr{X}=B$, but if $\mathscr{Y}\subseteq\mathscr{X}$ is finite, $\bigcap\mathscr{Y}\supsetneqq B$.

Answer (score 1):

Easily.

Take $A=\Bbb N$ and $B$ the even numbers there. Now take $X=\{B\cup(\Bbb N\setminus\{0,\ldots,n\})\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$. Namely, $X$ is the family of sets which are the even numbers and all the odd numbers above $k$.

Clearly $\bigcap X=B$, but there is no finite subfamily of $X$ whose intersection is $B$.